# How to override default do_action output in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to override the output in the footer of a Wordpress theme. The given section just has a `do_action('action_name')`

In my functions.php I've added:

```
add_action('action_name', 'action_name');
function action_name() {
    echo "<p>Additional text</p>";
}
```

However, this outputs the content I wish to replace along with the content I want to add. I'm fairly new to themeing Wordpress so I'm fairly lost here. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you can find which function is doing the output you want to remove you can use [remove_action()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action) to remove it:

```
remove_action( $tag, $function_to_remove, $priority );
```

To find this you will have to look through the code of the theme or plugin that generates it. Somewhere will be a `add_action()` call similar to yours. Note the function name and priority and use `remove_action()` along with it in your plugin/theme.

The hard solution would be to remove all functions for that action with [remove_all_actions()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_all_actions).

Afterwards you can add your own output as you are doing now.

**Note:** Be mindful that using `remove_all_actions()` is not advisable on all actions. For example, the action [wp_footer](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_footer) is used to load JavaScript at the end of the page. Removing all functions there will render plugins and themes that depend on it useless.

Answer (score -1):

Check `add_action` related code here-

> add_action ( string $tag, callable $function_to_add, int $priority =
>   10, int $accepted_args = 1 )
>
> **$tags**  (string) (Required) The name of the action to which the
>   $function_to_add is hooked.
>
> **$function_to_add** (callable) (Required) The name of the function you
>   wish to be called
>
> **$priority** (int) (Optional) Used to specify the order in which the
>   functions associated with a particular action are executed. Lower
>   numbers correspond with earlier execution, and functions with the same
>   priority are executed in the order in which they were added to the
>   action. Default value: 10
>
> **$accepted_args** (int) (Optional) The number of arguments the function
>   accepts. Default value: 1

Have a look over below thread hope this will help you-

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/